# Many form-TextBox' in one List<TextBox>

Tags: c#, list, textbox

I've got a form with 20 `TextBoxes(2-22)` and I would like to add them all the a `List<TextBox>` So I can add the same text for example in all of them using the `for-statement`.

What I thought(Lol.):

```
List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

for(int i = 2; i < 23; i++) {

//This String should refer to = textBox2, textBox3, etc
textBoxes.Add("textBox"+ Convert.ToString(i));

}
```

But this won't work because It can't convert a string to a textBoxName.
You can do this:

```
  textBoxes.Add(textBox2);
  textBoxes.Add(textBox3);
  textBoxes.Add(textBox4);
  ...So on
```

But ain't nobody got time for that... :)

Answer (score 2):

If it's WinForms this should work...

```
textBoxes.Add((TextBox)Controls.Find("textBox" + i, true)[0]);
```

Comment: This has some invalid arguments, Even when I converted 'i' to a string.

Comment: @NickPeelman, It works like a charm for me, after I added the cast to `TextBox`

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast them as controls before passing them into your list rather than trying to put a string value in your `List<TextBox>`.

Try adding this into your loop instead:

```
textBoxes.Add((TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textBox"+ Convert.ToString(i),true));
```

Comment: Error: No overload method "find" takes 1 argument

Comment: I combined your and Jens' code together and it worked. =

`textBoxes.Add((TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textBox" + Convert.ToString(i), true)[0]);`

Comment: sorry, was missing the ",true" bit to searchAllChildren http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find.aspx

Comment: Is it possible this only adds the text to the array? Not the object itself? I want to change the backColor of them too.

Comment: No, if you cast them to TextBox, then it is adding the actual controls in to your array. Update the question if there are other issues and add more code

Comment: Ye I was wrong. I overlooked a previous mistake and it works all, my apology :3

Answer (score 0):

```
List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 22; i++) {
    textBoxes.Add((TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textBox" + i, false)(0));

}
```