# How to put multiple textbox value into an array by a for loop

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

I got several textbox object on designer interface, let's say txtF1_ZHTW, txtF2_ZHTW, txtF3_ZHTW.

How to put the value of this 3 textbox into an array by a for loop?

The syntax I used for now is the worst way:

```
fieldName_TW[0] = txtF1_ZHTW.Text;
fieldName_TW[1] = txtF2_ZHTW.Text;
```

For what I want to proceed is something like...

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    fieldName_TW[i] = txtF[i+1]_ZHTW.Text;
}
```

So, how can I modify the code to use a for loop to enter the value of multiple textbox to an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your textboxes in a collection, such as a `List<TextBox>`, so you can iterate it.

```
var texboxes = new List<TextBox>()
{
  txtF1_ZHTW,
  txtF2_ZHTW
};

// ...

foreach(var textbox in textboxes)  // Assumes that  fieldName_TW is large enough
   fieldName_TW[i] = textbox.Text
```

Comment: For further issues that might appear when adding Textboxes to a List see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797447/many-form-textbox-in-one-listtextbox

Comment: I reference to the URL and get success!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797447/many-form-textbox-in-one-listtextbox

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rely on a name to make that kind of loop. Make a collection of your textboxes and add them in the right order, so you can use correct indexes to read them:

```
List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>() { txtF1_ZHTW, txtF2_ZHTW, txtF3_ZHTW };
```

Use the for-loop you already showed:

```
for(int i=0; i < textBoxes.Count; i++)
{
   fieldName_TW[i] = textBoxes[i].Text;
}
```